# Conditional selection of Custom Error Pages

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-backend, october-form-controller

I'm need to have different custom error pages based on where an error occurs

If an error occurs on

> Controller A => Show Custom Error A

Similarly, if error occurs on

> Controller B => Show Custom Error B.

This is because Controller B outputs javascript, and it needs to output javascript on error.

The custom error pages are set in `/modules/system/classes/ErrorHandler.php`, how can I write my own logic for custom error template selection in my own plugin. How can I override `/modules/system/classes/ErrorHandler.php` in my plugin

Al

Answer (score 0):

First You need to find some logic that `you can identify that this error is coming from Controller A or B`, you need some custom logic here,

> To override you can use this code inside your `plugin.php`  in `boot` method

```
<?php namespace HardikSatasiya\DemoTest;

use System\Classes\PluginBase;
use Event; // <- don't forget to add this one

class Plugin extends PluginBase
{
    public function boot() {

        Event::listen('exception.beforeRender', 
            function ($exception, $httpCode, $request) {

            // you need to write some logic here so you can identify
            // where from error is raising ( Controller A or B)
            // and show proper message
            dd($exception);


            // if error is not relavent to you just PASS it

            // return null to pass on this listener
            // it will call default system exception handler
            return null;

        }, 1); //<- set priority to 1, As default handler has 0 so
    }

    .... some code
```

**2nd scenario if you are able to raise and exception on your own you can use this one and its better as it shows where from Exception is raising**

> https://octobercms.com/docs/services/error-log#exception-handling

```
// App::error(function(YOUR_EXCEPTION_CLASS $exception) {
App::error(function(InvalidUserException $exception) {

    // you can return whatever you want
    return 'Sorry! Something is wrong with this account!';
});
```

you can also combine this with 1st solution where you can compare `$exception` object against the one which you throw from `controller` and `get idea its from controller A or B` then show proper message

> **for example**: `throw from controller`

```
use Cms\Classes\CmsException;

throw new CmsException('some message');
```

> will be handled by `put this also in plugin boot method`

```
use App;
use Cms\Classes\CmsException;

App::error(function(CmsException $exception) {
    return 'I will Handle CmsException ONLY !';
});
```

if you have any further doubts please comment.